# How to remove empty string in a list?

Tags: python, list

For example I have a sentence

```
"He is so .... cool!"
```

Then I remove all the punctuation and make it in a list.

```
["He", "is", "so", "", "cool"]
```

How do I remove or ignore the empty string?

Comment: Just a reminder that some english words [*contain* punctuation](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen). Depending on how you intend to use this, you may need to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), with `None` as the key function, which filters out all elements which are `False`ish (including empty strings)

```
>>> lst = ["He", "is", "so", "", "cool"]
>>> filter(None, lst)
['He', 'is', 'so', 'cool']
```

Note however, that `filter` returns a list in Python 2, but a generator in Python 3. You will need to convert it into a list in Python 3, or use the list comprehension solution.

`False`ish values include:

```
False
None
0
''
[]
()
# and all other empty containers
```

Comment: Be careful however, as this will return a `list` in Python 2 and a `generator` in Python 3.

Comment: what happens if you have `['']`?

Comment: @MattO'Brien since the list has an element, it is non-empty, and therefore it is considered `True`ish.

Comment: A `False` inside a `True`, eh

Answer (score 25):

You can filter it like this

```
orig = ["He", "is", "so", "", "cool"]
result = [x for x in orig if x]
```

Or you can use `filter`. In python 3 `filter` returns a generator, thus `list()` turns it into a list. This works also in python 2.7

```
result = list(filter(None, orig))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
cleaned = [x for x in your_list if x]
```

Although I would use regex to extract the words:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = 'This is some cool sentence with,    spaces'
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)', sentence)
['This', 'is', 'some', 'cool', 'sentence', 'with', 'spaces']
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you the answer to the question you *should* have asked -- how to avoid the empty string altogether. I assume you do *something* like this to get your list:

```
>>> "He is so .... cool!".replace(".", "").split(" ")
['He', 'is', 'so', '', 'cool!']
```

The point is that you use [`.split(" ")`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split on space characters. However, if you leave out the argument to `split`, this happens:

```
>>> "He is so .... cool!".replace(".", "").split()
['He', 'is', 'so', 'cool!']
```

Quoth the docs:

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

So you really don't need to bother with the other answers (except Blender's, which is a totally different approach), because split can do the job for you!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> text = "He is so .... cool!"
>>> [w.strip(punctuation) for w in text.split() if w.strip(punctuation)]
['He', 'is', 'so', 'cool']
```

Comment: In order to avoid calling `w.strip(punctuation)` twice, `l = [w.strip(punctuation) for w in text.split()]` and then `[w for w in l if w]` wuld be preferable...

Comment: @glglgl I'm okay with calling it twice in this case, but yes that is also an option. I would rather use a generator though

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out empty strings very easily using a list comprehension:

```
x = ["He", "is", "so", "", "cool"]
x = [str for str in x if str]
>>> ['He', 'is', 'so', 'cool']
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 returns an `iterator` from `filter`, so should be wrapped in a call to list()

```
str_list = list(filter(None, str_list)) # fastest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ["He", "is", "so", "", "cool"]
lst = list(filter(str.strip, lst))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a `filter`.

```
a = ["He", "is", "so", "", "cool"]
filter(lambda s: len(s) > 0, a)
```