# Removing all empty elements from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Why does my code not remove the last empty element in the list?

```
templist = ['', 'hello', '', 'hi', 'mkay', '', '']

for element in templist:
    if element == '':
        templist.remove(element)

print (templist)
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'hi', 'mkay', '']
```

Comment: `templist = [x for x in templist if x != '']` or `templist = list(filter(None, templist))`.  Assign to `templist[:]` if you want to mutate the original list.

Comment: Question was marked as duplicated, but you can find my answer (with explanations why your code doesn't work) here: https://gist.github.com/ischurov/028f2636c97f1e1a83f04ff10332a04d

Answer (score 31):

Well, you could always just do this:

```
new_list = list(filter(None, templist))
```

Comment: This returns `<filter object at 0x7ff4fcdff6d8>`

Comment: That's why filter is within a `list()`. In python 3 filter() returns a filter object while in python 2 filter returns a list. So, in python 3 you need to do `list(filter())`

Answer (score 12):

Because you are mutating the list that is being iterating over. Think of it as if the for loop is iterating using an index; removing elements reduces the length of the list thereby invalidating indices > `len(list) - 1`.

The "Pythonic" solution to this is to use a list comprehension:

```
templist = ['', 'hello', '', 'hi', 'mkay', '', '']
templist[:] = [item for item in templist if item != '']
```

This performs *in place* removal of items from the list.

Comment: A) this is a dup. B) `[item for item in templist if item]` is sufficient. Empty strings evaluate to false.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: A) a dup of what? B) I didn't want to make the assumption that items such as `None`, 0, and other items that evaluate to `False` should be removed. The OP states "empty element" - `0` and `None` are not _empty_.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: oh I see, the question is a dup, not this answer. This answer is different to that accepted in that question (it mentions in place replacement), and, although the concept is the same, this question pertains to empty strings, not empty lists.

Comment: There are other more "accurate" [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099694/how-to-remove-empty-string-in-a-list), but they have worse quality answers. Still very, very duplicate.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: OP asks _why_  their code does not work. The other question simply asks how to remove items from a list. There is a fundamental difference so, not "very, very duplicate" at all. None of the answers in that question address the reason. This is a better example of a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896752/removing-item-from-list-during-iteration-whats-wrong-with-this-idiom

Comment: **If whitespace should count as empty too**, such as `"      "`, add an `and not item.isspace()` after `item != ''`. `str.isspace()` returns `True` when the string consists only of whitespace (blank characters), but not when the string is completely empty.

Answer (score 6):

To point out your error, by iterating through a copy of the list, i.e changing your `for` statement to:

```
for element in templist[:]:
```

Altering a list while you iterate over it leads to the odd results you see.

More compactly, you could use `filter` for this:

```
templist = list(filter(None, templist))
```

when `None` is supplied to it, it simply returns elements that are true (empty strings evaluate to false).

Answer (score 2):

You could make a new list called `wordGrabber` for example and instead of removing the blanks you could populate your new list with content

```
templist = ['', 'hello', '', 'hi', 'mkay', '', '']

for element in templist:
    if element != '':
        wordGrabber.append(element)

print (wordGrabber)
```

Comment: Please review [how to format code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in your answers.  I have edited your answer so that the code is formatted.